# MongoDb C# Driver 2.0 Coalesce (or equivalent)?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a coalesce equivalent in MongoDb C# driver? Google comes up with nothing (it barely comes up with anything for SQL coalesce).

What I am trying to do is say "Select documents matching field1 value, if field2 is null. However, if field 1 is null, select all items matching value in field2. Both of them will never be null.

The SQL equivalent is this:
COALESCE(Column1.Id, Column2.Id) as stuffToFilterBy

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: Thanks Robert. I actually did a search through the docs for "coalesce," but found nothing. Would have felt like an ass if I put "checked the docs" too in my post like I almost did. Anyway, that should be what I need.

Comment: It's the first match in Google if you search for "mongodb coalesce".

Comment: Edit: It's for the command shell, not the C# driver. Found the command in the driver docs though.

Comment: @VSO If you found the answer, you should consider self-answering your question.